# Unable to refer to immediately destructured props in class component, do I have to use `this.props` every time?

Tags: reactjs, components, destructuring

In a stateless functional component, we can use destructured `props` as the function arguments:

```
const Blah = ({ hello, world }) {
  return <div>{hello} {world}</div>
}
```

This gives very clean code and not only is it obvious what props are being passed, we don't have to use `this.props` everywhere.

Having to use `this.props` all the time in a `class` component can take up a lot of room all over the component and is not nearly as nice to use:

```
class Blah extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.hello} {this.props.world}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

My questions is, what similar approach can we take for `class` components so that we don't have to use `this.props` everywhere?

One solution I can think of would be to destructure the `props` in the `render` method, but of course you would have to do that for every method in your `class` should you want to use the destructured name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope I'm afraid there's no way to. The functional component is essentially a `render()` function of a class component, the "cleaniness" is kinda the same actually (: